# How to make PocketSphinx use ALSA? (instead of pulseaudio or jack)

Tags: audio, alsa, pulseaudio, speech-recognition

I've been struggling to make pocketsphinx work with the audio system of my raspberry pi. As stated in [pocketsphinx's website](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/raspberrypi), one of the steps to build it for a raspberry pi is to execute this:

```
./configure --enable-fixed
```

What this does is to setup the environment prior to actually compile the program. I just have ALSA installed (no PulseAudio, no JACK), but configure continues to say that I has found JACK. So, when I run make, it compiles sphinxbase to use JACK. Then, when I try to run pocketsphinx, of course it fails with the following message:

```
jack server not running?
FATAL_ERROR: "continuous.c", line 246: Failed to open audio device
```

Why does pocketsphinx want to use JACK? How can I force it to use ALSA (which is the only audio system available by the way).
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure looks for the presence of the development libraries of PulseAudio, Jack and ALSA, **in that order**.

That is why in answers like [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10384/speech-processing-on-the-raspberry-pi/10392#10392) it is mentioned that *"...It also appears that ALSA will not be used if PulseAudio is installed..."*.

In my particular case, I didn't have anything else installed besides ALSA. But then I remembered that I did some tests with JACK, not by installing the actual package but compiling it by hand and things like that.

Those tests left behind the file **jack.h**, and configure found it.
I have manually renamed that file to jack.h.disabled (prior to actually deteting it) and now configure outputs this:

```
checking pulse/pulseaudio.h usability... no
checking pulse/pulseaudio.h presence... no
checking for pulse/pulseaudio.h... no
checking jack/jack.h usability... no
checking jack/jack.h presence... no
checking for jack/jack.h... no
checking alsa/asoundlib.h usability... yes
checking alsa/asoundlib.h presence... yes
checking for alsa/asoundlib.h... yes
checking for snd_pcm_open in -lasound... yes
```

I then completed the necessary steps for building and installing pocketsphinx and now everything works ok! So remember, install alsa development package (*sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev*), be sure not to have puleaudio or jack installed, and look carefully for the output of the *configure* command.